# Parallel programming in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, parallel.foreach

I have a simple For Each loop in a Button's click even, which looks like so:

```
    Protected Sub SelectAllButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SelectAllButton.Click
    RadGrid1.AllowPaging = False
    RadGrid1.Rebind()
    For Each item In RadGrid1.Items
        TryCast(TryCast(item, GridDataItem)("template").FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked = True
    Next
    SaveSelectedRFPs()
    RadGrid1.AllowPaging = True
    RadGrid1.Rebind()
End Sub
```

Now inside that for each loop there could be upwards of 100k records to loop through and I know there has to be a more efficient way to accomplish this, maybe parallel programming?

@Nico Schetler:

I tried that, here's how the code looks

```
    Protected Sub SelectAllButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SelectAllButton.Click
    RadGrid1.AllowPaging = False
    RadGrid1.Rebind()

    Parallel.ForEach(RadGrid1.Items.AsQueryable.Cast(Of GridDataItem).ToList(), Sub(item)
                                                                                    TryCast(TryCast(item, GridDataItem)("template").FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked = True
                                                                                End Sub)
    SaveSelectedRFPs()
    RadGrid1.AllowPaging = True
    RadGrid1.Rebind()
End Sub
```

But that gives me a **Source is not IEnumerable<>** error when I try to run it.

Comment: Have you tried with `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: Are you really displaying 100k items to the user? That doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: You should be working with the underlying business object instead, not directly with your grid, in order to modify data in it. What are you trying to do? Why do you need to set checked state on one of the columns over 100K rows? Perhaps you can do a DB query instead?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong... (no, seriously)

Don't you want to select every term in the array?

Currently, as far as I can tell, when you perform actions on your selected set, you check which one is checked. Maybe add a parameter to SaveSelectedRFPs() that determines whether to save selected RFPs or  **unselected ones**. That saves you the entire loop process. Of course, you lose the visual effect, but it may be worth it to the customer for a massive performance advantage.

```
Public Sub SaveRFPs(SelectedOrUnselected As Boolean)
 If selectedRFP.Checked = SelectedOrUnselected Then
    selectedRFP.save()
 End If
End Sub
```